# How to save two NSTextFields together?

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift2, nstextfield

I want to save and retrieve linked NSTextField.

I have three NsTextField:

```
ord_num_field
ord_rig_field
ord_product_field
```

I want to save these NSTextFields linked together so that when I retrieve `ord_num_field` the app retrieves relative `ord_rig_field` and `ord_product_field`.

How can I do this using Swift 2 in an OS X app? I have to use a form instead more individuals NSTextField?

Comment: Is there just one group of these or do you need to save many sets of related fields?

Comment: i have to save a lot of these sets

Comment: for example, in lotus notes i create forms; users insert information into this form and after that they save the form and the information are saved all together to compose a document. Every times that users compile a new form and save it, different document is created. i want to obtain the same result

Comment: I suggest reading about CoreData.  It is designed for the purpose of providing persistence for custom objects.  In your case, you can create a new type of managed object that contains your fields, then save and read it as a single entity.  (OS X documents -- NSDocument -- is also an approach but is probably overkill for a 3-item "form".)

Comment: i use 3 item only for these answer, really i have about 15 items. Thank for your answer, were the info i was looking for.